# SNS Topic Types

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sns

Can we create sns topic for application? I asked this because I have seen only examples that use Protocol='email' or 'sms' for subscribing to the topic using boto3. The requirement I have is that I want to create a topic and will subscribe to this topic using Endpoint Arn. So that when I publish notification to this topic it will be broadcasted to all its subscribers. So is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

To reproduce your situation, I tried this code:

```py
import boto3

sns_client = boto3.client('sns')

response = sns_client.subscribe(
    TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:foo',
    Protocol='application',
    Endpoint='arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:app/GCM/MyApplication'
)

print(response)
```

I don't have a valid EndpointARN for a mobile app, so I received the error:

> botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Subscribe operation: Invalid parameter: Application endpoint arn invalid:arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:app/GCM/MyApplication

However, it does prove that `Protocol='application'` is accepted as valid input.

I am using boto3 version `1.24.38`.

Comment: When I tried using Protocol='application'. I got an error like this : 
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Subscribe operation: Invalid parameter: Invalid protocol type: application

Comment: I tried your code for a invalid endpointarn and got the exact error as yours. But when I gave a valid endpoint I got the invalid protocol type: application error.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two types of topics: Standard-Topics and FIFO (First in, first out) Topics.

What you're referring to is the subscription. You can subscribe to an SNS topic using a variety of protocols:

- HTTP/HTTPS
- Email/Email-JSON
- Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose
- Amazon SQS
- AWS Lambda
- Platform application endpoint (Mobile Push Notifications)
- SMS

Read the docs for more details: [To subscribe an endpoint to an Amazon SNS topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-create-subscribe-endpoint-to-topic.html)

From your vague description, you're probably looking for an HTTP/HTTPS subscription.

Comment: I referred to this document for subscribing to a topic using python boto3 :https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.subscribe
an in this document it clearly mentions that the attribute Protocol can have 'application' as value. But when I gave application it gave this error botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Subscribe operation: Invalid parameter: Invalid protocol type: application

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved now. Our topic was a fifo topic and when we changed it to Standard Topic the subscribe function was working.